# How do I call a function from an Child unknown child class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the following 3 classes:

```
class Item
{       
   protected String itemType;

   public String getItemType()
   {
      return itemType;
   }
}

class Weapon:Item
{
   private int power;

   public int getPower()
   {
      return power;
   }
}

class Armour:Item
{
  private int defence;

  public int getDefence()
  {
     return defence;
  }
}
```

Weapon and Armour inherits properties from Item.

Then a function likes this.

```
public Item getItem()
{
  return new Weapon();
}
```

My problem is I need to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Item item1 = getItem();

if(item1.getItemType().Equals("weapon"))
    lblText = item1.getPower();
else
    lblText = item1.getDefence();
```

I obviously get error messages stating that the class Item doesn't have a function like getDefence() or getPower().
Does anyone know how I can manage to do this?

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to learn about properties and C# naming conventions - currently this code reads more like Java than C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `getItemType()` to accomplish what you need. You can do that using the C# `is` operator. Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx).

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type. For example, the
>   following code can determine if an object is an instance of the
>   MyObject type, or a type that derives from MyObject:

```
if (obj is MyObject)  
{  
}
```

You can change your code to this:

```
Item item1 = getItem();

if (item1 is Weapon)
{
    lblText = ((Weapon)item1).getPower();
}
else if (item1 is Armour)
{
    lblText = ((Armour)item1).getDefence();
}
```

Also, according to C# naming conventions you should use *camel casing* for your method names so instead of `getDefence()` it should be `GetDefence()`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve wanted behavior, you need to cast an `item1` object of type `Item` into type `Weapon` or `Armour` respectively.

For example:

```
if(item1.getItemType().Equals("weapon"))
    lblText = ((Weapon)item1).getPower();
else
    lblText = ((Armour)item1).getDefence();
```

Also, be aware that the casting will throw an exception at runtime if your `item1` object contains `itemType` which is not equal to "weapon" string. Mainly, because `getItem()` method creates an object of type `Weapon`.